# find_elements_by_xpath returns None after recursive call

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have something like this:

```
def get_next_src(self):
    if len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath/to/img)) > 0:
        return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath/to/img).get_attribute("src")
    else:
        time.sleep(5) # wait until image is loaded
        self.get_next_src() # recursive call
```

I check if there is something in my `xpath` and then I get attribute `src`. However since I am iterating though gallery image sometimes doesn't load correctly so I have to wait and repeat the call.

Now whenever I get to recursive call and it calls the function again it returns `None`. But If I do it like this without recursive call just repeat the `if` statement from above:

```
def get_next_src(self):
    if len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath/to/img)) > 0:
        return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath/to/img).get_attribute("src")
    else:
        time.sleep(5) # wait until image is loaded
        # repeat the if statement from above
        if len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath/to/img)) > 0:
             return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath/to/img).get_attribute("src")
```

I get the `src` tag correctly.

**Why do I get `None` by calling it recursively and get the correct `src` attribute when I repeat the `if` statement**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_next_src(self):
        if len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath/to/img)) > 0:
            return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath/to/img).get_attribute("src")
        else:
            time.sleep(5) # wait until image is loaded
            return self.get_next_src() # recursive call
```

Try doing return self.get_next_src(), in your case you are just calling the function.